# Enable php files in child directories?

Tags: php, apache

I installed Cent OS 6.5 and I added Apache and PHP.

If I put some file in `/var/www/html/` I can view them in my browser. The problem is, if I put a directory there and some files in the directory, I can't browse them and I get `Forbidden` error.

I don't want to use .htaccess due to performance and security concerns. How can I configure httpd.conf in order to fix the `Forbidden` error?

Comment: Check the permissions of the folder. Apache probably can't see the file/folder. You need to folder to be at least `0755` and the file to be at least `0644`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions of the folder. Apache probably can't see the file/folder. You need to folder to be at least `0755` and the file to be at least `0644`.

If you are using ssh, you should probably setup a umask to set the default permissions of files/folders you create. Or else you will run in to this every time you create a file/folder.

Comment: Yes, it's a permissions problem but "at least 0755 and the file to be at least 0644" is nonsense.

Comment: @symcbean: Please let me know how that is "nonsense". Typically the files won't be owned by the apache user and the files only need read permissions to execute as they are interpreted scripts.

Comment: Typical. For anyone doubting the permissions, I'll just refer you to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096255/what-permissions-for-php-scripts-directories

Comment: Thanks - I voted that one down as well. File ownership and permissions should reflect a SECURITY MODEL. If you have no security model then setting the permissions as you suggest will allow them to be read. Sometimes 0755/0644 is the right answer. For my security model it's 2775/0664. And to support file uploads, 0777 and 0666 with direct web acces disabled. But in the case of some models it might be 0750/0640