# Apache 2 web server and linux how to manage file structures and permissions

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, cakephp-3.0

I have been using Apache-2.0 server in my laptop, initially I used to get many problems regarding permissions so I changed permissions for my root directory /var/www/html like **chmod -R 777** www. After then I was free from permissions error and all.Now my root files contains admin,css,js,images,index.php etc... Consider my APP which I developed is a social networking site.Now I don't know which permissions should I give to the server and users of that website in order to load it on web-browser properly.
please someone explain what are the necessary things and permissions that we should set to our files.It would be more helpful if the explanation contains a structured format and specific permissions.And explains how these permissions are set to Apache server.

EDITED: Some more help.thanks for suggestions.They clarified some basic doubts but I need some more clarity regarding file structures.suppose when user uploads a image file and I'm saving it to image folder as specified but when I use those pics to load in the page through permissions denied error is occurring.So generally ***how a project area is set up (especially file structures)*** in order to free from all these errors.Thanking you...

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, 644 on files and 755 on folders - as for making sure everything's running with the right ownership, you might have to google that for yourself.  Mind telling us the name of the app so we can avoid it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permissions for PHP scripts/directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096255/what-permissions-for-php-scripts-directories)

Comment: thanks for your reply it clarified some general doubts but I need some more clarity regarding file structures.suppose when user uploads a image file and I'm saving it to image folder as specified but when I use those pics to load in the page through permissions denied error is occurring.So generally how a project area is set up in order to free from all these errors.