# What should be the permissions for folders under html directory for web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, apache, amazon-ec2

This is related to linux web directory structure and more specifically amazon EC2 server. The default directory is `/var/www/html` and I have put my website's folder into this directory. But before uploading them to server using FileZilla, I got this error:

**Permission Denied.**

To solve this I gave 777 permission to HTML folder and everything worked. But this isn't safe. I don't know what permission should I give to HTML folder and what permissions should for my custom web folder and files.

Here's my folder structure

`/var/www/html/chat`

```
node_modules
config
controllers
public
..css
..js
..images
..img
app.js
index.html
login.html
```

This is a NodeJs web app. So what should be the permissions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permissions for PHP scripts/directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096255/what-permissions-for-php-scripts-directories)

Comment: Node.js apps aren't served directly by other web servers. They shouldn't go under /var/www/html at all.

Comment: @Quentin so where should I put them? And even if I put them in some other directory, I would need to give write permission to directory to upload them. So again this permission confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically file permissions for /var/html/www would belong to root user.As you are uploading files from filezilla,you will treated as home user as ec2-user.So you are getting Permissions denied error.you can do two things

1.upload your files in your  user home directory i.e ec2-user.OR

2.add the ec2-user(as it is the default username for amazon AMI) to root group [useful-link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213958/can-i-add-myself-to-group-root) and upload to /var/html/www/ with drwxrwxr-x (775) permissions.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @VikasKumar Please check the edited answer. I hope that helps you.

Comment: why r-x permission for others?